# Pandas isin() function for continuous intervals

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I want to construct a dummy variable that is true if a number is between 1 and 10, I can do:

```
df['numdum'] = df['number'].isin(range(1,11))
```

Is there a way to do that for a continuous interval? So, create a dummy variable that is true if a number is in a range, allowing for non-integers.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to do     `df['numdum'] = df[(df.number > 1) & (df.number < 11)]`

Comment: You could do something like `df[['number']].query('number >= 1 and number <= 11')` but store the query as a variable you can pass to `query`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Series` objects (including dataframe columns) have a [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) method:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 20, 8))
>>> s
0     0.000000
1     2.857143
2     5.714286
3     8.571429
4    11.428571
5    14.285714
6    17.142857
7    20.000000
dtype: float64
>>> s.between(1, 14.5)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that this function is inclusive by default.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
df['numdum'] = (df.number >= 1) & (df.number <= 10)
```

Comment: That returns a boolean mask rather than the values where that mask is true

Comment: @EdChum: but isn't that what the OP is after?  This is the continuous analogue of `isin(range(1,11))`.

Comment: @DSM ah I get it I thought the OP wanted the values rather than the mask to use, at least that is my understanding now

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the same thing with `cut()`.  No real advantage if there are just two categories:

```
>>> df['numdum'] = pd.cut( df['number'], [-99,10,99], labels=[1,0] )

   number numdum
0       8      1
1       9      1
2      10      1
3      11      0
4      12      0
5      13      0
6      14      0
```

But it's nice if you have multiple categories:

```
>>> df['numdum'] = pd.cut( df['number'], [-99,8,10,99], labels=[1,2,3] )

   number numdum
0       8      1
1       9      2
2      10      2
3      11      3
4      12      3
5      13      3
6      14      3
```

Labels can be `True` and `False` if that is preferred, or you can not specify the label at all, in which case the labels will contain info on the cutoff points.